# What the air pressure inside an air bubble in water

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, water, fluid-statics

I am a newbie in physics and have a homework problem, I hope I am not asking something stupid, since I don't learn physics nor am I going to do anything advanced with it.

So let's say we have a bubble under water, with a radius of $0.5\mathrm{\mu m}$, $\sigma = 73\mathrm{mN}/\mathrm{m}$, in a depth of 5m with atmospheric pressure being 1000hPa.
Does anyone have a good answer to this?

($\sigma$ is for surface tension, I think)

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Also, I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm writing this answer because others are saying that the surface tension is a small correction to the internal pressure.  Instead, **the pressure due to surface tension is the largest factor** because $ 0.5 {\rm \mu m}$ is a very small bubble.  (The other answers are right in their outline of the physics, imho, just not accounting for the smallness of the bubble.)

For a bubble, pressure difference balances the surface tension.

$$\Delta P = \frac {2\sigma} {r}$$

The important point is that the smaller the bubble, the larger the pressure difference.  Using your numbers, I get about 2.8e5 Pa = **2.9 atm**.

That is, the pressure due to surface tension is the dominant factor in this small bubble.

Comment: Thank you very much, good answers, we will look into it with the boys :D, since we have a test tmrw

Comment: Principally good answer, except that 4T/r is the pressure inside a soap bubble. For a water bubble there is only one surface, i.e. 2T/r.

Answer (score 1):

The bubble's pressure will be equal to the pressure of its surroundings, plus a very small amount of additional pressure due to the surface tension of water.  This means that as the bubble rises, the pressure on the bubble reduces, and the volume of the bubble increases to keep an internal pressure that is very slightly higher than its surroundings.  This expansion of bubbles as they rise in a water column can clearly be seen in video footage of bubbles in water.

Comment: Ok thank you, would you also know an equation to calculate the exact bubble pressure? Like a whole equation so I can implement it later.

Comment: Oh and thank you also, good answer

Answer (score 0):

The additional pressure due to surface tension is computed according to the [Young-Laplace equation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young-Laplace-Gleichung). The atmospheric pressure is the baseline, and adds to this, of course. The additional weight pressure of the water column above the bubble is computed according to [Pascal's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_law). As a rough guideline, 10m water column correspond to a weight pressure of about one atmosphere (try it out yourself by inserting the values, this is a very useful rule, for example when you are a diver!).

So in a depth 5m you have roughly 1.5 atmospheres (weight of water + ambient), i.e. 1500 hPa. To that you have to add the pressure of surface tension as sketched above. Just enter the values.

Comment: I mean, great answer but i have no idea how the Yound Laplace equation works, plus i only got the variables i have specified above, i dont have any more information about the homework, is it even doable? Like just using a regular calculator, i am in high school btw.

Comment: You have the radius given and the surface tension (which is $\gamma$ in the Wikipedia article, not $\sigma$). It is doable, even in elementary school.

Comment: Yup, i am rusty i have to say, online school doesnt have a positive effect on my knowledge.

Comment: Then you should even be pressing more to get going. ;-)

Comment: Yea, i guess youre right.

Comment: I'm guessing that the bubble would have to be non-spherical to let the surface tension compensate for the fact that the fluid pressure on the bottom of the bubble is greater than on the top.